# Matlab: how to find fundamental frequency of a speech

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I am new to Matlab and speech processing as well. I want to find the fundamental frequency of speech signal to determine the gender of the speaker. I removed the silence from the signal by analysing it within 10 msec periods.

After that I got the fft using this code :

```
 abs(fft(input_signal_without_silences))
```

My plot of both the speech signal and the fft of it is below:

[image]

Now, I want to find the fundamental frequency but I could not understand which steps do I need to do this. Or do I misunderstand this concept?

As far as I have learnt, there are some methods like autocorrelation,

**Since I am not familiar to both speech processing and matlab, any help and advice is very much appreciated.**

Comment: I found this lecture to be enlighting and comprehensive: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/courses/spsci/matlab/lect10.html

Answer (score 0):

The fft() help can solve most parts of your problem. I can give a brief overview of things based on the content of the help file.

At the moment what you are plotting is the two sided, unnormalized fft coefficients, which don't tell much. Use the following to get a more user informed spectral analysis of the voice signal. Using the single sided spectram you would be able to find the dominant frequency which might be the fundamental frequency of the speech signal.

```
y = [];                       %whatever your signal
T = 1e-2;                     % Sample time, 10 ms
Fs = 1/T;                     % Sampling frequency

L = length(y);                % Length of signal 

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

% Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('|Y(f)|')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a plot of Amplitude vs Sample Number instead of a plot of Amplitude vs Frequency.In order to calculate the fundamental frequency you need to find the frequency that corresponds to the highest frequency.

Matlab returns frequencies from -fs/2 to fs/2 so the frequency at index n is

**f = n * (fs/N) - (fs/2)**

where f = frequency, fs = sampling frequency, N = number of points in FFT.

So basically all you need to do is get the index where the plot is highest and substitute it in the equation above to get an estimate of the fundamental frequency.Make sure *n > N/2* so that your fundamental frequency is positive.